# Word 2007 customisation - template based addins vs. custom dlls written in Visual Studio?

Tags: templates, office-2007, add-in, word-2007

I'm planning an upgrade to Word (Office) 2007 and need to decide now which customisation route to take.

The current set-up is Office 2000 with templates acting as addins, loading with Word (from the startup folder) to support a lot of functionality - interface with DMS, interface with CRM, user form behaviour and printing to name but a few.

As generic templates are used they call the tools stored within the addins to display data, format documents and print to specific trays etcetera.

Will there be any advantage in terms of speed, stability and usability in writing a set of dlls to replace the addin templates?  The generic templates would then reference these instead.

My instinct is that this will be the case, however, does anyone have any concrete arguments for or against such an approach?